# Why can't I read drives properly?

Tags: 11.04, usb, mount, disk

I installed Natty and my perfectly functioning Ubuntu has stopped working - specifically, it has stopped reading disks. I think the problem has to do with Disk Utility not loading (though Ubuntu can see USB and DVD drives, but not mount them), so I tried it through command prompt and got this:

```
sudo palimpsest
libgdu:ERROR:gdu-pool.c:2369:device_recurse: assertion failed: (depth < 100)
lee@lee-desktop:~$
```

I'm not being lazy - I have now spent three days trying different things to fix it, Please Help!

Comment: Can you add more information on what else you've tried?

Comment: have a look at this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/571038 Problem seems to be related to the order of your partitions. It has some comments and tips on checking your system (fdisk -l).

Answer (score 2):

A patch has been proposed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/571038

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with ubuntu config,which is still not patched by canonical.So to avoid it you may have to degrade to 10.10